# How do I change the font color in a tableview cell to a variable UIColor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, fonts, colors

I am adding the color here but it is not reflecting in the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = theFontColor;//this does not work
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//this works
    // Configure the cell.

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

The comfigureCell was overriding the color. Sorry was a real noob error.

Comment: Check if -configureCell:atIndexPath: isn't overriding the color you're setting earlier. The described method should work assuming theFontColor is set.

Comment: Thanks Warkst for confirming that it should work, I ran through and found that although theFontColor was being set it ran cellForRowAtIndexPath first and caused a NSInternalInconsistencyException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined somewhere theFontColor as a UIColor

You should do for example:

```
     UIColor *theFontColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:64.0f/255.0f green:58.0f/255.0f blue:43.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

...and then use it

Comment: I was setting theFontColor BUT it was only after I was trying to use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Thanks for the help :)